# Looping Through PHP array, error log saying undefined constant

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array $data that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [section] => Array
        (
            [345dfg] => Array
                (
                    [test] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => John
                        )
                )
            [567fghj] => Array
                (
                    [test] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Tom
                        )
                )
        )
    [othersection] => Array
        (
            [result] => 2
        )
)
```

I am trying to loop through each item in `section` so am doing this...

```
foreach ($data[section] as $section) {

    echo $section[test][name];

}
```

It is working correctly but in my error log I get...

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant section- assumed 'section' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you have typo error $data['section'], array index accessible with single or double quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose array keys with a single quote as they are of type string.

So,

```
foreach ($data[section] as $section) {
```

Should be

```
foreach ($data['section'] as $section) {
```

Otherwise, without `$` sign and without a single quote, `section` is considered as `constant`.

Possibilities with `$data['section']`:

1) `$section` as a Variable: `$data[$section]`

2) `section` as a Constant: `$data[section]`

3) `section` as a array key (string): `$data['section']`

It is always a good practice to enclose array keys with single quotes.

As by coincidence if the same constant is defined, the value of that constant may be considered as the array key.

If constant not defined, it will show a warning.

Comment: same thing will do in this echo $section["test"]["name"];